# The water floods in my mouth

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

So I was wondering if native speakers use ‘flood in’ for water not for people or crowds. For example,

> I can't open my mouth while inhaling in the pool, the water just floods in

Like that. I looked up this phrasal verb on dictionaries and they say Flood In can be used for crowds to emphasize the number of them. If the sentence above sounds odd, what are the other verbs there for me to use in that context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Flood" is a water-related verb.  Any use with things other than water (such as crowds or people) is *metaphorical*.  So, yes, it is natural to say water "floods in" to something.

However when you say water flooded into your mouth when swimming, it implies a far greater amount of water than you would expect, as if you were in danger of *drowning*.

> As the storm raged he tried to turn the boat into the oncoming wave but it hit squarely broadside.  He yelled in surprise as water rushed over the gunwales, and in a moment, **flooded in to his open mouth**, leaving him gasping and choking. He barely held on to the tiller to avoid being swept overboard.

Instead you can say something less dramatic such as

> my mouth **fills up** with water

or

> water always **gets into** my mouth and nose

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you give is correct. It is a little *hyperbolic* since your mouth is quite small for a flood.

It is certainly possible to say

> The pipe broke and the water flooded my kitchen
>
> Don't open the door. The river has burst its banks; if you open the door the water will flood in.